# Number Format Exception results from reading data from text file

Tags: java, eclipse

I have this code to read data from text file and store it into a 2d array the data is really big so that one line can be considered as 10 lines in the text file and I have several lines.

```
try{
read_blockage=new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\ahmadgmsalt535465123\\Desktop\\MOEAFramework-2.3\\Blockage Output1.txt"));
int row = -1; // since we're incrementing row at the start of the loop
while(read_blockage.hasNext()) {
    row++;
    String[] line = read_blockage.nextLine().split("\t");
    for(int j=0;j<Input.General_Inputs.Num_Of_Ppes;j++){
        try {
            General_Inputs.Blockage_Number[row][j] = Double.parseDouble(line[j]);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }}
read_blockage.close();}catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

but I am having this error

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2043)
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)
    at Input.Get_Inputs(Input.java:277)
    at Input.main(Input.java:288)
```

this error is repeated several time I am not sure why this error occur any recommendation?

Comment: Check the contents of the file you opened from java program. It has #VALUE instead of number at some line number.

Answer (score 0):

The error shows that you are trying to parse the String "#VALUE!" as Double. and which is not acceptable.

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "#VALUE!"
```

Check your input file and parse accordingly.

Please see [java doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble%28java.lang.String%29) for more information.

Comment: Can I send the file to you the file is look very normal to me it contains only numbers

Comment: Yes, that will be great, sathish.palaniappan@gmail.com

Comment: Thank you very much really appreciate it I already sent the data

Comment: Now the problem is that your file contains `"1` somewhere.  Seriously, you ought to READ the error messages.